# PHP | FPDF : Space between 5th and 6th cell

Tags: php, fpdf

I am troubling in generating this report..

I am aiming something like this

[image]

But I only have this

[image]

I want the 5th and 6th cell to have a space between them..

and here is my code so far:

```
$pdf = new PDF('L', 'mm', array(215.9, 330.2));
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    $pdf->Cell(132);
    $pdf->Cell(45,15,'Teacher'."'s ".'Table',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Ln(25);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult)){

        if($pdf->GetX() < 290){
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
            $pdf->Cell(30,15,$row['stud_fname'].", ".$row['stud_lname'],1,'','C');
        }else{
            $pdf->Ln(20);
        }

    }
    $pdf->Output();
```

any idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the cells and create an 'invisible' cell between the 5th and the 6th.

**EDIT:** I think your current code is wrong, when `$pdf->GetX() > 290` you are creating a new line BUT are also skipping the mysql result (you are not writting it). I have updated my answer with what I think is right.

```
$thisCell=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult)){
    if($pdf->GetX() >= 290){
        $pdf->Ln(20);
        $thisCell=1;
    }
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->Cell(30,15,$row['stud_fname'].", ".$row['stud_lname'],1,'','C');
    if ($thisCell==5)
        $pdf->Cell(10,15,'',0); //cell without borders
    $thisCell++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response sir, I tried your code but the all cells aligned vertical..